# ctx is a required argument

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a simple music bot. When I execute the command I get this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.`

This is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "-")

class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    """Custom Exception class for connection errors."""
    ...

class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""
    ...

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@bot.command(name='connect', aliases=['join'])
async def connect(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    await ctx.send(f'Connected to: **{channel}**', delete_after=10)


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

The command should move the bot into the voice channel in discord.

This is the full traceback:

```
Full traceback:
Ignoring exception in command connect:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 859, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 718, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 682, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 596, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 442, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Can you show full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commands should only accept a `self` parameter if they are [part of a cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#cogs).  Remove the parameter:

```
@bot.command(name='connect', aliases=['join'], pass_context=True)
async def connect(ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
    ...
```